# How to skip loading a project in MonoDevelop/Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, monodevelop, projects-and-solutions

I have a Visual Studio (2010/2012) solution that contains multiple projects; some are in WPF and therefore incompatible with MonoDevelop (version 3.0.5) or Mono.

When I open the solution in MonoDevelop, I get a popup saying (for each project that is incompatible):

`Could not load project '{project path}' with unknown item type {60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}`

I could remove the specific projects from the solution file, but then I would need to maintain two solution files (one for Visual Studio, one for MonoDevelop).

I already know how to skip specific projects during the build (in the build configuration); I am looking for any similar way to silently fail/skip specific projects when loading the solution, to avoid the popup. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Have u tried to unload them ?

Comment: In MonoDevelop I can only see an option to Reload them.

Comment: Ona  side-note, if you want to open the project, just google for the (problematic) guids. The first few hits will all tell you what external stuff it requires (happenens for things like MVC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Unity 5.4.2f2 on OSX El Capitan 10.11.16 and creating and opening my first script in MonoDevelop 5.9.6 I got the same popup error:
`Could not load project'Assembly-CSharp.csproj' with unknown item type '{...}'`

I solved it by navigating to the following menu and enabling MonoDevelop Assembly Browser:

**MonoDevelop-Unity > Add-in Manager > Installed > IDE Extensions > MonoDevelop Assembly Browser > Enable**

Answer (score 1):

You can open the solution in Visual Studio, right click on the projects you need to exclude one by one and select `Unload Project` from the menu. Save your solution and open it in MonoDevelop.

All you need to do is to click on `Load Project` in the same location when you open the solution again in Visual Studio.

[image: Unload Project]

Answer (score 0):

Try skipping compilation for that project.

You can also define your own compilation configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On mono you can try to check if C# language bindings are enabled. In my case they were not and that solved it.

Add-in manager -> Language bindings -> Enable C# binding